# How to convert the column into one hot encoded column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, one-hot-encoding

I have a column in my DataFrame as shown below:

```
City

1) London
2) Birmingham
3) Lahore
4) Paris
    .
    .
```

I want to convert this column into one hot encoded . The output should look like as :

```
   City

1) [1,0,0,0]
2) [0,1,0,0]
3) [0,0,1,0]
4) [0,0,0,1]
```

code showing output :

```
    pd.get_dummies(dff['city (S)'], prefix='city_')

    city__Kingston  city__Liverpool city__London    
    0                   0               0
    0                   0               0
    0                   0               1
    0                   0               0
```

I want in  a single column only , not separate

Answer (score 0):

Hard to be sure without actually looking at the data but something like this should do the trick:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.get_dummies(df['City'], prefix='city_')
```

Comment: I don't want the output in separate columns , I want it in a single column as shown in my question , I have edited that how your code is showing the output

Answer (score 0):

You could use the OneHotEncoder from sklearn

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
oe = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
df['City'] = oe.fit_transform(df['City'])
```

sparse=False shows all the 0.

Comment: It does not answers me because it is still giving error of reshape , I am reshaping but error still remains same